# ASP.NET Web API Self-Host both HTTPS and HTTP in single service?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a public self-hosted ASP.NET Web API service that exposes two controllers. One of them I would like to have accessible only via HTTPS, and the other I don't.  Can this be done within a single service?  If so, can you provide a few hints?  It seems like I would need to register two base addresses, but I don't see how that's possible for a single service.

Comment: Hi Lee, did you manage to get to the bottom of this?

Comment: @mcintyre321 I haven't tackled it yet, but I'm leaning towards converting my service from "self-hosting" to using "IIS" for three reasons:  Better help page integration, better support for both HTTP and HTTPS, and better deployment upgrade options.

Comment: Yeah, maybe thats easier!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create two HttpServer instances, one for http and one for https.  I've been trying to find out why this limitation exists because I know HttpListener can handle registering both for the same listener.

Anyway, if creating two HttpServer instances really doesn't work for you then you will need to look at the Katana project and the Microsoft.Owin.HttpListener.  That does support multiple addresses but unfortunately the default Katana startup code doesn't!  But I have it on good authority there is a way to customize the HttpListener on startup to make it possible.

Comment: Darrel, thanks for the response. I am glad to hear that the HttpListener _can_ handle registering both addresses.  I'll take a look into the Katana project.  I suppose the other option is to switch away from Self-hosting. Or I could leave both controllers accessible via HTTPS for now. Will mull over all the options.

Comment: @Darrel could you share some links on how to enable the ssl(https) for self-host application? I've encountered many issues by following some posts by google.

Comment: @Shawn My good friend Pedro Felix covers all of this in our book http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001708/ch15.html#_using_tls_with_self_hosting

Answer (score 0):

Because HttpListenerBase (of ServiceStack.Host.HttpListener) does not override its Listener if not-null when starting then the following could be done in your host class which inherits from HttpListenerBase:

```
public override ServiceStackHost Start(string urlBaseNoPrefix)
{
    // Here urlBaseNoPrefix is something like "web.acme.com/app/" 
    Listener = new System.Net.HttpListener();
    Listener.Prefixes.Add("http://" + urlBaseNoPrefix);
    base.Start("https://" + urlBaseNoPrefix);
    return this;
}
```