# Katana or Microsoft.Owin.HttpListener for Servicing both http and https in a single service

Tags: c#, https, asp.net-web-api2, owin, katana

I'm having trouble in understanding the way to implement both `https and http` in a `single service`.

I have a `OWIN hosted Web API`. Currently it serves http only. I like to implement ssl for it. Creating `two http server instances` does the job but this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483917/asp-net-web-api-self-host-both-https-and-http-in-single-service) says that Katana or Microsoft.Owin.HttpListener can be used to accomplish this purpose.
How is that possible using `Microsoft.Owin.HttpListener`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by getting https set up: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/wiki/Selfhosting

Then you just need to add both the http and the https url when you start the service:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/f3a8d848b7548e62d52737efa0a4fc9cf6c6cedf/src/Microsoft.Owin.Hosting/StartOptions.cs#L39
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/f3a8d848b7548e62d52737efa0a4fc9cf6c6cedf/src/Microsoft.Owin.Hosting/WebApp.cs#L34

What do you call today to set the url?

Comment: I'm currently using `WebApp.Start<Startup>(BaseAddress);` to assign base address to API. `netsh http add urlacl ...` to reserve that base address.

Comment: Ok, you just need to call the overload that takes a StartOptions and give it both urls.

Comment: Can u add the overload in your answer?

Comment: That was the https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/f3a8d848b7548e62d52737efa0a4fc9cf6c6cedf/src/Microsoft.Owin.Hosting/WebApp.cs#L34 link.